# In javascript , how to read the enum value?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, razor, enums

I have created json variable called "**grouptypejson**" as mentioned below:-

```
var grouptypejson = {
    "opt": [
             {
                "n": "@SampleResource.GENERIC",
                "v": 0
             },
             {
                "n": "@SampleResource.DEPARTMENT",
                "v": 1
             }
           ]
};
```

The above json variable is defined globally in cshtml page under javascript body.

I am using hardcoded value i.e. "v":0 & "v":1

Instead of using hardcoded value, I want to get the number via enum which is defined under models namespace i.e. mentioned below:-

```
namespace My.Sample.Models.Enums
{
    public enum FilterEnum
    {
        Generic = 0,
        Department,
        All
    }
}
```

I want to read the value using the above enum and store the same at hard coded place

i.e. `"v":0 & "v":1`

I don't know how to get the enum value as integer and store at "v".

I tried using the following mentioned below but the result was **Generic** & **Department** respectively. Replaced 0 & 1 with the below string at the above json variable.

```
 "v":"@FilterEnum.GENERIC" & "v":"@FilterEnum.DEPARTMENT"
```

Please guide me how to do the same, I am including the enum namespace in my html page.

Please correct me if i have written anything wrong. I am beginner & learner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast enum to int:

```
var grouptypejson = {
    "opt": [
             {
                "n": "@SampleResource.GENERIC",
                "v": @((int)SampleResource.GENERIC)
             },
             {
                "n": "@SampleResource.DEPARTMENT",
                "v": @((int)SampleResource.DEPARTMENT)
             }
           ]
};
```

Comment: It is throwing an error: CS1525: Invalid expression term 'int'